# ScalaJS Uncaught TypeError: (0 , $m_Lorg_scalajs_jquery_package$(...).jQuery$1) is not a function

Tags: scala, scala.js

I am reading this tutorial for ScalaJS

https://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/

As you can see in my build.sbt, that I have included the reference to the jQuery library

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

// This is an application with a main method
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true

name := "ScalaJSTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.1",
   "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.1"
)
jsDependencies += RuntimeDOM
skip in packageJSDependencies := false
jsDependencies +=
   "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4" / "2.1.4/jquery.js"
```

I have also included the jsDeps and the jquery library in my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Scala.js Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Include Scala.js compiled code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./target/scala-2.12/scalajstest-fastopt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./target/scala-2.12/scalajstest-jsdeps.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also did

```
npm install jsdom
```

This is my scalajs code

```
import scala.scalajs.js.JSApp
import org.scalajs.dom
import dom.document
import org.scalajs.jquery.jQuery
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSExportTopLevel

object ScalaJsTest extends JSApp {
   def main() : Unit = {
      jQuery(() => setupUI())
   }
   def appendPar(node: dom.Node, text: String) : Unit = {
      jQuery("body").append(s"<p>$text</p>")
   }
   @JSExportTopLevel("addClickedMessage")
   def addClickedMessage(): Unit = {
      appendPar(document.body, "You clicked the button!")
   }
   def setupUI(): Unit = {
      jQuery("#click-me-button").click(() => addClickedMessage())
      jQuery("body").append("<p>Hello World</p>")
   }
}
```

But still my code gets the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , $m_Lorg_scalajs_jquery_package$(...).jQuery$1) is not a function
    at $c_LScalaJsTest$.appendPar__Lorg_scalajs_dom_raw_Node__T__V (scalajstest-fastopt.js:2341)
    at $c_LScalaJsTest$.main__V (scalajstest-fastopt.js:2332)
    at scalajstest-fastopt.js:6848
    at scalajstest-fastopt.js:6849
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to include the script tag with `jsdeps` *before* the one for `fastopt.js`. Otherwise, by the time your main method runs, jQuery has not been loaded yet.